# How do I do recursive multiplication when one or both of the factors is/are negative?

Tags: java

```
public static int multiply2(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        return num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 - 1);
    }

}
```

I just realized that it would be fun to make a program that could determine the product of two numbers, one or both being negative. I want to do it using recursive multiplication (basically repeated addition). Could some one help me out? Thanks!

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Baz : `one or both being negative.`

Comment: i've tried setting more params in the if statement, i want to know what area of my program is causing the trouble because i used the program above as is and it gave me the first number just fine but i had 6 method calls of multiply2. The other five calls returned a stackOverflow error.

Comment: wow, such a firestorm of answers :D

Comment: i'd really like to give you guys all points for being awesome, i had the logic of the program in mind but i just didn't know how to translate that into java code, too bad this forum doesn't allow that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0) {
        return 0;
}

else if( num2 < 0 ) {
    return - num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 + 1);
}

else {
    return num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would test if it's negative and subtract instead of add:

```
public static int multiply2(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if(num2 > 0){
        return num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 - 1);
    }
    else{
        return -num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Durp, I put 2 instead of 1 in the num2 > part. Should work now.

Comment: so in `num1 x num2` is `num2` is zero, output `num1` that doesn't seem right.... 0*1=0

Comment: And one more fix, your base condition was right to start with :P

Answer (score 3):

```
else if (num1 < 0 || num2 < 0) {
    int signum1 = num1 < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    int signum2 = num2 < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    return signum1 * signum2 * multiply(signum1 * num1, signum2 * num2);
} else {
```

Something like that

Note: there is a [`signum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum%28double%29) function and `Math.abs` can be used for `signum * num`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add if number is -ve. If you see we are adding only first number and for second number condition we have to reach is `0`. So if negative do`+1` if positive do `-1`

```
        else if (num2 < 0)
            return -num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 + 1);
         else
            return num1 + multiply2(num1, num2 - 1);

    System.out.println(multiply2(5, -6));-->-30
    System.out.println(multiply2(5, 6));-->30
```

Comment: @DavidWallace  It works properly. I have updated the result. Reason it works is only first number is being added and loop terminates on 0

Comment: It does NOT work properly.  You have demonstrated that it gives 30 as the result for 5 x -6.  But 5 x -6 is NOT 30.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yup. A dumb mistake. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dealing with it multiple times in the main recursion part, a better idea would be to handle it as an edge case and just convert it into a regular case since both the assignment and return will not occur until the mathematical operation has finished.
To do this, I converted y into a positive number and then negated the result of the function as a whole once the result has returned to the negative case.

Here's my solution:

```
private static int product(int x, int y) {
    // Negative start edge case
    if (y < 0) {
        return -1 * product(x, y * -1);
    }

    // Edge case (only for speed)
    if (y == 0 || x == 0) {return 0;}

    // Base case
    if (y == 1) {
        return x;
    }

    // Recursion
    return x + product(x, y-1);
}
```

It's worth noting that even with out the 0 edge case, the method would still work. In this case the method would just need to make a few more than necessary to get the result.

Testing has concluded that this method works with either parameter being 0 and/or negative.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int multiply2(int num1, int num2) {
    if (num1 == 0 || num2 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        int sign2=(int)(Math.abs(num2)/num2);
        return sign2*num1 + multiply2(num1,num2-sign2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

David Wallace's answer is good but if the input is (1,124) or (-1,124) the depth of recursion (number of times the method calls itself) will be 123, not very efficient. I would suggest adding a couple of lines to test for 1 or -1. Here's a full example:

```
public class Multiply {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("product = " + multiply(1, 124) );
    }

    public static int multiply(int x, int y) {
        System.out.println("Multiply called: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);

        if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
            System.out.println("Zero case: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
            return 0;
        }

        else if (x == 1 && y > 0) {
            return y;
        }

        else if (y == 1 && x > 0) {
            return x;
        }

        else if ( x == -1 && y > 0) {
            return -y;
        }

        else if ( y == -1 && x > 0) {
            return -x;
        }

        else if( y == -1 ) {
            System.out.println("y is == -1");
            return -x;
        }

        else if( x == -1 ) {
            System.out.println("x is == -1");
            return -y;
        }

        else if( y < 0 ) {
            System.out.println("y is < 0");
            return -x + multiply(x, y + 1);
        }

        else { 
            System.out.println("Last case: x = " + x + ", y = " + y);
            return x + multiply(x, y - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Multiply called: x = 1, y = 124
product = 124
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I am actually working on this one for homework. *Recursive solutions implement - or use - a base case against which the need to continue is determined*. Now, you might say, "What on Earth does that mean?" Well, in laymen's terms, it means we can simplify our code (and, in the real world, save our software some overhead) - about which I will explain, later. Now, a part of the issue is understanding some basic math, namely, **a negative plus a negative is a negative** or **minus a positive** ( -1 + -1 = -2) depending upon the math teacher to whom you speak (we'll see that come into play in the code, below).

Now, there **is** some debate to be had, here. About which I will write, later.

Here is my code:

```
public static int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0) 
    {
        return result;
    } 
    else if (a < 0) // Here, we only test to see whether the first param.  
                    // is a negative
    {
        return -b + multiply(a + 1, b); // Here, remember, neg. + neg. is a neg.
    }                                   // so we force b to be negative.
    else 
    {
        result = result + b;
        return multiply(Math.abs(a - 1), b);
    }
}
```

Notice there are a two things done differently, here:

1. The code above does not test the second parameter to see whether the second parameter is negative (`a < 0`) because of the mathematical principle in the first paragraph (see **bold text** in first paragraph). Essentially, if I know I am multiplying (*y*) by a negative number (*-n*), I know I am taking *-n* and adding it together *y* number of times; therefore, if the [multiplicand or multiplier](http://www.factmonster.com/ipka/A0881931.html) is negative, I know I can take either of the numbers, make the number negative, and add the number to itself over and over again, e.g. -3 * 7 could be written (-3) + (-3) + (-3) + (-3)... etc. *OR* (-7) + (-7) + (-7)
2. **NOW HERE IS WHAT'S UP FOR DEBATE:** That above code does not test to see whether the second number (`int b`) is `0`, i.e. multiplying by `0`. Why? Well, that's personal choice (sort of). The debate here must weigh the relative significance of something: the overhead for each choice (of either running an  equals-zero test or not). If we *do* test to see if one side is zero, each time the recursive call to multiply is made, the code must evaluate the expression; however, if we do *not* test for equals zero, then the code adds a bunch of zeros together *n* number of times. In reality, both methods "weigh" the same - so, to save memory, I leave out the code.